# Insertion Failed with TEXT data type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

I have a sample table with one of the column called Expression with the TEXT data type. This is the data I am going to insert and the number of characters in that string is 504 characters.

```
Expression="CASE WHEN (txt_Second_23.TYPE_OF_AUTH='OP' or txt_Second_23.TYPE_OF_AUTH='OPS') then '1' else (CASE WHEN ((txt_Second_23.TYPE_OF_AUTH='IP' or txt_Second_23.TYPE_OF_AUTH='IPN') and ((txt_Second_23.Requested_Provider_NPI is not null or txt_Second_23.FACILITY_NPI is not null) OR (txt_Second_23.Requested_Provider_Last_Name is not null or txt_Second_23.Facility_Name is not null) OR (txt_Second_23.REQUESTED_PROVIDER_CITY is not null or txt_Second_23.FACILITY_CITY is not null) OR (txt_Second_23.abcdef) END"
```

Whenever I tried to add one more character to the above string, it's not allowing to insert. Can anyone please let me what is causing the issue or am I missing something here.

**Note:** I have changed the data type from TEXT to VARCHAR(1000), still no luck.

**Update:** This issue is happening while inserting it through programatically with prepared statement. I am able to insert when I do it manually by creating sample table with expression column.

This is the actual string I am trying to insert.

```
CASE WHEN (txt_Second_23.TYPE_OF_AUTH='OP' or txt_Second_23.TYPE_OF_AUTH='OPS') then '1' else (case when ((txt_Second_23.TYPE_OF_AUTH='IP' or txt_Second_23.TYPE_OF_AUTH='IPN') and ((txt_Second_23.Requested_Provider_NPI is not null or txt_Second_23.FACILITY_NPI is not null) OR (txt_Second_23.Requested_Provider_Last_Name is not null or txt_Second_23.Facility_Name is not null) OR (txt_Second_23.REQUESTED_PROVIDER_CITY is not null or txt_Second_23.FACILITY_CITY is not null) OR (txt_Second_23.REQUESTED_PROVIDER_STATE is not null or txt_Second_23.FACILITY_STATE is not null) OR (txt_Second_23.requested_provider_zip is not null or txt_Second_23.facility_zip is not null))) then '1' else null end) END
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: TEXT is much bigger than varchar(1000) so that's not where the problem is.

Comment: Agreed, just for trail verified with varchar(1000).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c78ea5b99a7fa559a7527642022bcb67 Edit the fiddle and try to reproduce.

Comment: Correct Akina, Even I have verified it locally. But, through programmatically failing if character size > 504. Able to insert programmatically till 504 characters as I said in the question.

Comment: I am not seeing any exception as well. For successful insertion I am seeing this message Execution of prepared statement took 2ms and 1 rows affected. For failure one, I am not seeing any message.

Comment: What do you mean 'through programmatically ' you only have mysql tagged - please add your code., what is expression defined as..

Comment: *This issue is happening while inserting it through programatically with prepared statement.* Cannot reproduce. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2013731b88eac6232eae312be55a4ff3 Create a fiddle with your prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

In my code some where expression column was appending to one more column called description and it's length is only 512 characters. That's causing the issue.

Taken care it by changing the data type from varchar(512) to text.